How to extract Copper from softgel?
I have an assignment. I need to determine the concentration of copper in a pharmaceutical product using UV-Vis spectroscopy. The product is Chophyll of Healthy America, a softgel that contains: copper gluconate, caramel, chlorophyll, glycerin and soy oil. What should I do?
When I try to obtain the content of the softgel and disolve it with water, the solution is dark green. I need to a clear solution to make a complex with ammonia but it was no possible for me.


A "clear" solution might mean not cloudy, like milk. A  clear green might be acceptable -- ask the instructor.. 2. If there is copper, the complex with ammonia is very strongly colored!


You’re right. A clear green solution is what I need. The Chrolophyll is the problem. How do I remove it? Can I precipitate it?

It all depends what you're trying to measure. If only copper, then there are a few ways to decompose all organic material, including chlorophyll, e.g., strong oxidants, heat, etc. If you're trying to determine other components, e.g., gluconate, it becomes more difficult.
